# EF Migrations - Skipping a named migration on command line rollback

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

Very simply, is there a way to hand the migrate.exe command line tool a "skip" argument, specifying one or more migrations that should not be rolled back?

Or, perhaps there's another way to achieve this. Here's the use case:

Current latest migration is `migration0`

1. developer 1 takes a branch off the baseline and adds a migration on Monday - call it `migration1`
2. developer 2 takes a different branch off the baseline and adds migration on Tuesday - `migration2`
3. developer 1 adds a migration on Wednesday - `migration3`
4. developer 2's change gets released to production and sticks - `migration1` has not been released
5. developer 1's changes get released to production, but have to be rolled back - since `migration1` was scheduled before `migration2`, `migration2` gets rolled back as well.

When releasing developer 1's changes, I want to be able to

```
update-database -targetmigration: migration0 -skip: migration2
```

from the migrate.exe command line.

Entity framework version is 5.

Comment: I dont know.   But it is little issues like that why i like automated migrations.  Db is altered to match context. I will watch to see if it can be done